# How to sign PDF using DocuSign API in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, pdf, docusignapi

I have just created DocuSign developer account. I have to sign PDF using my signature and send it recipients in C#. I don't want recipient to sign using https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email . I have already PDF available in my system, I need to sign using DocuSign API and send it to recipient for read only purpose.

I am referring E-SIGN REST API samples - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/ but didn't get sample code to sign document.

Comment: We could really do with an example of what you are doing in the post.  I know you have posted links, but they could be virus links for all we know and who has got the time to wait for a page to load when they are trying to help as many people as possible in their lunch break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to be able to sign a document programmatically with the eSignature API. You can use the [DocuSign Signature Appliance](https://developers.docusign.com/dsa-api) to programmatically sign a document w/o user interaction. It is an on-prem piece of equipment designed for a high volume of digital signatures. While this is technically possible, It might not be what you're really looking for.

You also mentioned that you do not want to implement "sign via email" functionality, and instead would prefer to facilitate an agreement in your app, then send it to an additional recipient for "read-only"

You might consider...[Embedding DocuSign within your app](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing). Your envelope will likely contain two recipients (one signer and one "witness"). To accomplish this, you will need to first create your envelope and then retrieve a recipientView from DocuSign, which you can embed in your site!

Here is are [some code examples](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp) that demonstrate this (and more) in C#